# Trouble getting mysql results to php variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code of:

```
$count = "select 
              count(fruit) as total,
              sum(fruit like '%apple%') as apple,
              sum(fruit like '%orange%') as orange
          FROM my_wonderful_table_of_fruits";

$count = mysql_query($count);
$count = mysql_fetch_row($count);
```

I'm trying to store these in a variable and can't seem to catch them :/

My code is:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($count)) {
    $count_total = $row['total'];
    $count_apple = $row['apple'];
    $count_orange = $row['orange'];
}
```

And I was expecting to be able to echo them like so:

`echo "$count_total[0] is the total of $count_apple apples and $count_orange oranges`

When I run this query in MySQL Admin, I get a nice row that looks like:

```
total    apple    orange
  5        3         2
```

Anyone know how what I'm doing wrong? (besides the fact that I'm using the 'evil' version of mysql_fetch_row)

Much appreciated!

Comment: "Anyone know what's wrong?" --- why do you think it is wrong? Provide your code in a single piece, not splitted. Do you perform `mysql_fetch_array` twice?

Comment: Please try to move to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). mysql_* are deprecated. If you are learning from a book teaching mysql_* functions, it is old and outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reanalyse what you're doing. Your SQL will only return one row with some aggregate results, but it seems you expect to be able to iterate over several rows of results (due to your `while()`).

What your sql does and how you're trying to use it are two different things.

Comment: Very true, I see what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since your query only produces one row, you can simplify it to the following:

```
list($total,$apple,$orange) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("
    SELECT COUNT(`fruit`) AS `total`,
      SUM(`fruit` LIKE '%apple%') AS `apple`,
      SUM(`fruit` LIKE '%orange%') AS `orange`,
    FROM `my_wonderful_table_of_fruits`"));
echo "$total is the total of $apple apples and $orange oranges.";
```

Comment: You say simplify, but I say mangle into a difficult-to-read command.

Comment: It's not pretty, but it works! Thanks Kolink! ...Just waiting to see if anyone has a neater way.